# Recursive Saving in Database

Tags: php, database, recursion

**Overview:**

I've been creating a dashboard framework that suited to my needs in every project that uses Slim 3. One of the features that I would like to implement is the workbench feature. That can create multiple workbench with widgets that the user can include. (Statistics, Single Data [Count], Table Data, etc..)

**Database Table Structure:**

[image]

- **user_workbench_id** = Primary Key | Auto Increment
- **user_id** = Foreign Key connected to sys_user (user table)
- **workbench_id** = Unique workbench identifier in user's id. (Meaning 2 different users can have the same workbench_id but a single user can't have a same multiple workbench_id)
- **workbench_parent_id** = Parent ID of workbench_id
- **layout_type** = Workbench layout type. Parameters: blank / null, split-horizontal, split-vertical, grid

**Front End View:**

[image]

To generate a recursive data, there must be at least a couple of workbenches.

[image]

Having said all that, is to give you guys an overview how the data will be generated with user experience. I'm also concerned by the speed of data will be saved or deleted in some way.

Now to store the workbench in my database I'm calling a method to my Controller.

```
public function saveWorkBench($request, $response, $args, $workbench_parent_id = 0, $workbenches = []) {

    if ($workbench_parent_id == 0 && empty($workbenches)) {
        $this->auth->user()->userWorkbench()->delete();
        $workbenches = $request->getParam('workbenches');
    }

    foreach ($workbenches as $workbench) {

        $this->auth->user()->userWorkbench()->create([
            'workbench_id'        => $workbench['workbench_id'],
            'workbench_parent_id' => $workbench_parent_id,
            'layout_type'         => $workbench['layout_type']
        ]);

        if (!empty($workbench['workbenches'])) {
            $this->saveWorkBench($request, $response, $args, $workbench['workbench_id'], $workbench['workbenches']);
        }
    }
}
```

What I'm doing here is whenever I save the workbench. I'm deleting all user workbench (truncate it per user who save / deleted workbench). Then loop all over again using recursive method to get the same data that the user generated.

The question is, is this acceptable? I feel that truncating and looping all over again is not good but I've seen this method a couple of times that's being used in a lot of data.

If this is not acceptable, any solution / advice for me to do this the good way? I've been thinking that I'll just update / deleted the specific workbench, but I have no idea how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, calling a controller action recursively doesn't seem an elegant solution. Move your "save workbench tree" logic in separate model.

Second, performance wise, it's better to update changes rather than deleting and re-creating the tree completely. But it's really up to you, and it mainly depends whether the amount of data is large and frequency of this operation is high. If it's not, just leave it as it its. "Premature optimization is the root of all evil (c) Donald Knuth".
And one more thing, make sure you perform all DB queries within a single transaction.